# how pass data between more than 2 activities Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to pass multiple variables between more than two activities.

I know how to pass between one to another, but not from the first to the third.

Activity One

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener {
  val i = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
  val variableOne= txtVariableOne.text.toString()
  i.putExtra("VARIABLEONE",variableOne)
  startActivity(i)
}
```

Activity TWO

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener {
  val i = Intent(this, Activity3::class.java)
  val VariableTwo = txtVariableTwo.text.toString()
  i.putExtra("VARIABLETWO",variableTwo)
  startActivity(i)
}
```

Activity THREE (This is what I need)

```
Log.d("DEBUG ", "Value: " + intent.getStringExtra("VARIABLEONE"))
Log.d("DEBUG ", "Value: " + intent.getStringExtra("VARIABLETWO"))
```

I need access `VariableOne` and `VariableTwo` from activity Three.

Thank

Comment: Passing data from activity to another, I think is a simple task that someone will answer below. But what I would suggest is to figure out if you can actually perform that same task in single activity using Fragments? Because what you are currently doing is highly inefficient in terms of performance as well as maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Activity TWO

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener {
  val i = Intent(this, Activity3::class.java)
  val VariableTwo = txtVariableTwo.text.toString()

  //THIS WHAT YOU NEED:
  i.putExtra("VARIABLEONE",intent.getStringExtra("VARIABLEONE"));

  i.putExtra("VARIABLETWO",variableTwo)
  startActivity(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity Two

```
 override fun viewAllNotes() {
    val intent : Intent = Intent(this, ViewAllNotesActivity::class.java)
     intent .putExtra("VARIABLEONE",variableOne)
    startActivityForResult(intent, VIEW_ALL_REQUEST_CODE)
  }


  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
    if (requestCode == VIEW_ALL_REQUEST_CODE){
  //get data here
        }
    }
    }
 }
```

Activity three

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result .putExtra("VARIABLEONE",variableOne)        
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    this.finish();
  }
```

Or else you can store the values using Shared-preference and get values  any where in the project

Comment: Thx, i try shared preference and its the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can say the same as we passing in java
There are many ways
From the one is, You can pass by intent when starting another activity which is proper when you think data at the time of starting the activity like bellow,

```
val intent = Intent(mActivity, LoginActivity::class.java);
intent.putExtra("keyName", data)
startActivity(intent)
```

Another way you can use preference or store data in preference and you can use where ever you need.